# How can a pullback dissimilarity on a nasty space be interpolated/approximated?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, distance, reference-request

I have a map $\gamma : X \rightarrow Y$ that is expensive to compute. $X$ is a nasty, very non-Euclidean, not even manifold-like, space of variable-length and "structurally inhomogeneous" sequences of things that might have discrete and/or continuous things under the hood (basically, assume $X$ is not nice to deal with). $Y$ is a finite space endowed with a *bona fide* metric $d$. There is a pullback pseudometric $d^*(x,x') := d(\gamma(x),\gamma(x'))$ and I know $d^*|_{W \times W}$ for some "small" $W \subset X$. I want to approximate $d^*$ on $X^2$, presumably using neural techniques.

**Are there known techniques/papers that address this problem?**

In "metric learning" as I understand it, one is given labels indicating either proximal or distal pairs and the goal is to learn a metric that fits these labels. This is not useful to me. Ideally I would want to "interpolate" $d^*|_{W \times W}$ but the non-manifold nature of $X$ is such that (say) radial basis function interpolation cannot possibly apply.

Comment: Seems like a default approach might be attributed sequence embedding of $W$ into some $\mathbb{R}^n$ followed by radial basis function interpolation on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. Hoping there is some more direct approach out there...